# XSLT not splitting sub child node correctly with for-each and value-of functions

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I receive an XML containing items, within this node is a sub node containing serial numbers.

My output file should have two main parent nodes, Document_Lines and SerialNumbers. Document_Lines contains ItemCode while SerialNumbers contains linenum, SerialNumber and Quantity

If quantity of item is greater than 1 then there will be multiple SerialNumbers rows.

Input is as follows:

```
<root>
    <rows>
        <row>0</row>
        <itemcode>MHAK2ZM</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <serials>
            <serial>123456</serial>
        </serials>
    </rows>
    <rows>
        <row>1</row>
        <itemcode>MHAK2ZN</itemcode>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <serials>
            <serial>124456</serial>
            <serial>124556</serial>
        </serials>
    </rows>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Document_Lines>
      <row>
         <ItemCode>MHAK2ZM</ItemCode>
      </row>
      <row>
         <ItemCode>MHAK2ZN</ItemCode>
      </row>
   </Document_Lines>
   <SerialNumbers>
      <row>
         <linenum>0</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>123456</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
      <row>
         <linenum>1</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>124456</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
      <row>
         <linenum>1</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>124556</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
   </SerialNumbers>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <Document_Lines>
                <xsl:for-each select="//rows">
                    <row>
                        <ItemCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./itemcode"/>
                        </ItemCode>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>    
            </Document_Lines>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <xsl:for-each select="//serial">
                    <row>
                        <linenum>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../row"/>
                        </linenum>
                        <SerialNumber>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../serial"/>
                        </SerialNumber>
                        <Quantity>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(../serial) div ../../quantity"/>
                        </Quantity>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SerialNumbers>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Document_Lines>
      <row>
         <ItemCode>MHAK2ZM</ItemCode>
      </row>
      <row>
         <ItemCode>MHAK2ZN</ItemCode>
      </row>
   </Document_Lines>
   <SerialNumbers>
      <row>
         <linenum>0</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>123456</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
      <row>
         <linenum>1</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>124456 124556</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
      <row>
         <linenum>1</linenum>
         <SerialNumber>124456 124556</SerialNumber>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </row>
   </SerialNumbers>
</root>
```

Number of SerialNumbers rows (3) is correct. But there should only be one serial number value per SerialNumber tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I created a variable within for-each loop.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <Document_Lines>
                <xsl:for-each select="//rows">
                    <row>
                        <ItemCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./itemcode"/>
                        </ItemCode>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>    
            </Document_Lines>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <xsl:for-each select="//serial">
                <xsl:variable name="serial" select="."/>
                    <row>
                        <linenum>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../row"/>
                        </linenum>
                        <SerialNumber>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$serial"/>
                        </SerialNumber>
                        <Quantity>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(../serial) div ../../quantity"/>
                        </Quantity>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SerialNumbers>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```